# Extracting SVG from Webpage using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, svg, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract **High Resolution** image from this website : http://target.lroc.asu.edu/q3/ given its latitude and longitude. I have written a python script which inputs the Latitude and Longitude automatically, but how do I extract this Lunar Map at that specific latitude and longitude using Python and selenium. Also, once extracted, I wish to save it as a .png file.

Below is the code that navigates to the page and enters lat and long values automatically.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from PIL import Image
import time 

#Taking the inputs from USER
latitude = input('Enter the Latitude : ')
longitude = input('Enter the longitude : ')

#Below is to remove the toolbar and open chrome and visit the webpage 
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('http://target.lroc.asu.edu/q3/#')

full = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="links"]')
full2 = full.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="smallHelpBox"]')
full3 = full2.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="fullscreen mapbutton"]').click()

arrow2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="zoomSelectWrapper mapbutton"]').click()
arrow3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="zoomSelect ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"]')
arrow4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="ui-menu-item"]')
arrow5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="ui-id-58"]')
arrow5.click()

arrow = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition_19" and @class="olControlMousePosition olControlNoSelect"]')
arrow.click()
trial = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="recenterWrapper"]')

trial.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class = "latbox"]').send_keys(str(latitude)) 
trial.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class = "lonbox"]').send_keys(str(longitude)) 
trial.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class = "recenterBtn qm-icon icon-recenter"]').click()
arrow.click()
```

Comment: At which stage are you trying to take the screenshot? Can you consider sharing with your exact manual steps? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB Basically I just do not want to click the screenshot, rather extract that high resolution image on the website. This might be similar to extracting a high res portion of a map from Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

After a page is loaded, especially a full page image like the one in this post, the image can be captured and saved to a file by a single selenium command.

```
driver.save_screenshot('/home/rebel/images/myscreen.png')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: save_screenshot function downloads a low resolution image. I want a high resolution image. This function takes the screenshot of all the things on the screen!!

Comment: Also this line of code has invalid syntax, since save_screenshot requires a string as an argument.

Comment: @RahulSharma I changed to path to a more practical string argument instead of using variable notation. Make sure to use a *valid* path on your system. Back to your actual need. Is it that you need to zoom in more to get the resolution you need? In short, this site does not provide an option to download the high resolution image **source**. You can zoom in, then take a snapshot of the zoomed page.

Comment: @RonNorris Thats what I am currently doing, but I wanted to know if there is a way to extract the High Res SVG image!!!!

Comment: @RonNorris But anyways, Thanks for you Help!

Comment: Not answering specifically the OP